# How to use the read command in Bash?

Tags: bash, built-in

When I try to use the `read` command in Bash like this:

```
echo hello | read str
echo $str
```

Nothing echoed, while I think `str` should contain the string `hello`. Can anybody please help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Related: [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/6862601) and [BashFAQ/024 - I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `read` in your script command is fine. However, you execute it in the pipeline, which means it is in a subshell, therefore, the variables it reads to are not visible in the parent shell. You can either

- move the rest of the script in the subshell, too:

  ```
  echo hello | { read str
    echo $str
  }
  ```
- or use command substitution to get the value of the variable out of the subshell

  ```
  str=$(echo hello)
  echo $str
  ```

  or a slightly more complicated example (Grabbing the 2nd element of ls)

  ```
  str=$(ls | { read a; read a; echo $a; })
  echo $str
  ```

Comment: Awesome examples!  I did have to slightly tweak it on OSX by putting spaces inside the curly braces, and a semi-colon after the echo, like this: str=$(ls | { read a; read a; echo $a; })

Comment: @javadba: It is not required twice. The given example returns the *second* item from `ls`. With a single `read a` you would get the first item. Don't ask me why the answerer chose this example.

Comment: To read three (or more) IFS-separated columns into variables one can do 'read VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3`.

Comment: keeps biting me. Should be documented in the man page..

Answer (score 43):

Other bash alternatives that do not involve a subshell:

```
read str <<END             # here-doc
hello
END

read str <<< "hello"       # here-string

read str < <(echo hello)   # process substitution
```

Comment: You can use a process for the here string as well such as `read A B C <<< $(echo 'aaa bbb ccc')`

Answer (score 8):

Typical usage might look like:

```
i=0
echo -e "hello1\nhello2\nhello3" | while read str ; do
    echo "$((++i)): $str"
done
```

and output

```
1: hello1
2: hello2
3: hello3
```

Answer (score 3):

The value disappears since the read command is run in a separate subshell: [Bash FAQ 24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Answer (score 2):

To put my two cents here: on KSH, `read`ing as is to a variable *will* work, because according to [the IBM AIX documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/read.htm), KSH's `read` *does* affects the current shell environment:

> The setting of shell variables by the read command affects the current shell execution environment.

This just resulted in me spending a good few minutes figuring out why a one-liner ending with `read` that I've used a zillion times before on AIX didn't work on Linux... it's because KSH does saves to the current environment and BASH doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

I really only use read with "while" and a do loop:

```
echo "This is NOT a test." | while read -r a b c theRest; do  
echo "$a" "$b" "$theRest"; done
```

This is a test.
For what it's worth, I have seen the recommendation to always use -r with the read command in bash.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need echo to use read

```
 read -p "Guess a Number" NUMBER
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative altogether is to use the printf function.

```
printf -v str 'hello'
```

Moreover, this construct, combined with the use of single quotes where appropriate, helps to avoid the multi-escape problems of subshells and other forms of interpolative quoting.

Comment: If that's all you're trying to achieve, you might as well do `str='hello`.  I think the point here is to capture the output of a command into a variable.

Answer (score -6):

Do you need the pipe?

```
echo -ne "$MENU"
read NUMBER
```

Comment: -1: your `echo` and `read` commands are not connected in any way.

Comment: The poster clearly wants an automated way to populate a variable without having to enter it manually.