# Changing the current working directory of invoking bash programmatically

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I have a file which contains key/value -pairs in the format

```
TAG PATH
```

. Now, I want to write a program that reads from the command line a **TAG**, and changes the current working directory of invoking **bash** to corresponding **PATH**.

How would I go about this?

Comment: "changes the current working directory of invoking bash" - Nope, try again.

Comment: @Kevin Nope, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It is impossible for a process to change its parent's environment, including the cwd.

Comment: You can look into writing a script you can source, or a shell function to put in your bashrc, however, as they run in the active shell.

Comment: @corerodde, Please add to your question more information. You want to make 'cd' to PATH, if current line contains 'TAG' word?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider something like (perhaps in your bash [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions))

```
while read tagname dirname ; do
   pushd $dirname ;
   dosomethingwith $tagname
   popd
done < yourinputfile.txt
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676045/how-to-use-read-command-in-bash) (about `read` in bash) and read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

[GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) might be a better tool.

Notice that you can only change the current directory of the current process using the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall (invoked by `cd`  or `pushd` or `popd` bash [builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands)). There is no way to change the directory of some other process (e.g. the parent or invoking one). The `pushd` and `popd` builtins also updates bash [directory stack](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Directory-Stack.html#The-Directory-Stack).

There is no way to change the current directory of the invoking shell (the parent process running in a terminal). But you may define your own bash function there. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to understand more about [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)