# Assign columns to variables in shell

Tags: shell, loops, variables, unix, multiple-columns

I have this file:

```
NC_003037.1     453555  454448
NC_007493.2     2279220 2278345
NC_007952.1     1763831 1762950
NC_005791.1     844089  844916
```

I want to iterate of each line to obtain  variables "id" "column1" "column2", that I will use in this command:

```
efetch -db nuccore -id $id -chr_start $column1 -chr_stop $column2 -format fasta > file.txt
```

Could you guide me with a way to do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

When you see multiple columns, think `awk`.

```
rm -f file.txt ; cat inputfile.txt | \
awk '{ print "efetch -db nuccore -id "$1" -chr_start "$2" -chr_stop "$3" -format fasta" }' | \
while read cmd; do $cmd >> file.txt; done
```

(EDIT: moved the re-direct into the execution)

The `awk` forms up the command, and then the `while read cmd ...; done` executes it.

Comment: Hi @Kingsley. Thank you for your answer. What I expected when I run the code is the creation of a file (o several files to each row) with the info that I query to retrieve, but this file it is not created using your code.

Comment: @DavidLópez - Ah yes, that `> file.txt` should be in the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7676045/6862601) loop:

```
while read -r id column1 column2; do
  efetch -db nuccore -id "$id" -chr_start "$column1" -chr_stop "$column2" -format fasta
done < file.input > file.txt
```

- it is important to use double quotes around variable expansions to prevent word splitting and globbing
- put `> file.txt` at the end of the loop for better I/O efficiency

---

Related:

- [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/6862601)

Comment: Thanks, @codeforester, it works, and also do the work that add each query to the end of the file, so I don't to deal with an incremental variable to produce several files and concatenate them .